# Unable to identify object uniquely using UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, browser-automation

I tried to automate the https://www.redbus.in website and book a seat.
I need to fetch the seat details of the top left corner seat of the upper deck.
UFT recognizes the entire seat layout as a webelement and not the individual seats.

I tried to get the Child objects but it contains nothing.

```
Set x = Browser("Book Bus Travels, AC Volvo").Page("Search Bus Tickets").WebElement("WebElement").ChildObjects
msgbox x.Count

For i = 1 To x.Count
y = x(i).GetRoProperty("Alt")
Msgbox y
```

[Redbus Seat Layout. Bangalore to Goa of any date any bus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTu3v.png)

I also tried using **.Object Method** and tried to look into the Native properties and operations but all my efforts went in vain.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: As @NicEndo said you should use image based identification for stuff under `canvas`, check out [UFT's Insight feature](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-and-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/252430)

Comment: Hi @Motti, Using insight feature I would be and I am able to identify the object but in my case I need to extract the data form the object/element.
Any idea how can we do this using UFT ?

Comment: You could try using UFT's [OCR option](http://eyeontesting.com/questions/7003/get-text-from-insight-object-in-uft.html), I'm not sure how powerful this is